# index multi-language field with luncene

Tags: lucene, multilingual

I have multi-language document records to index with lucene. That is, each document record is in one language, but there are different language records.  I intend to keep them in one index so that I could search with multi-language queries.  Currently the document records are in one data input file like this:

```
<DOCID>1<\DOCID>
<LANGUAGE>CHINESE<\LANGUAGE>
<TEXT>中文内容<\TEXT>

<DOCID>2<\DOCID>
<LANGUAGE>ENGLISH<\LANGUAGE>
<TEXT>Some English text<\TEXT>
```

My question is: Is there a way to use different analyzers for the same  field with one index writer?  Or should I split the document records into two input document in different languages to apply different index writer but append to the same index?

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the Analyzer you intend to use for a document when you call [IndexWriter.addDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocument%28java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29).

However, you would probably benefit more from splitting different language texts into different fields,  This would prevent having hits on the wrong language, and allow you to just create an [`AnalyzerWrapper`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/AnalyzerWrapper.html) to assign the appropriate analyzer after having detected the correct language.

Comment: I'll proceed with your suggestions. Thank you!